# why is autowire setter value not set?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a class like this

```
public class ServiceImpl {
private boolean required = false;

public ServiceImpl (Log log) {
    this.db = Registry.getDatabase(this);
    this.log = log;
    rt = new Table(log, db);
    it = new ItemTable(log, db, rt);
    gt = new GroupTable(log, db);
}

public ServiceImpl () {
      this.db = Registry.getDatabase(this);
      log = Registry.getLog(this);
      rt = new Table(log, db);
      it = new ItemTable(log, db, rt);
      gt = new GroupTable(log, db);
}
public void trySomething(Collection someList, int value) {
     for(int i=0; true; i++){
        try{
          doSomething(someList,value);
          return;
        } catch (..) {
        ...
        }
     }
}

public void doSomething(Collection someList, int someValue) {
...
    //sysout(required) - prints false (expected to be true...)
    if(!required) { 
         execute A
    } else {
         execute B
    }
...
}

public setRequired(boolean required){
    this.required = required
    //sysout(required) - prints true
}
```

Class Two (one level up)

```
abstract class Synch {
...
private ServiceImpl service;
protected synch(Log log, ServiceImpl service, Keys key) {
this.log = log;
this.key = key;
this.service = service;
}
....
void execute(){
try{
service.trySomething(someList,someValue);
}..

protected abstract void service() throws LockException(){
return service;
}
....
```

for my xml

```
...
<bean id="service" class="com.ort.ets.ServiceImpl">
     <property name="required" value="true" />
</bean>
...
```

Sorry to ask if something is obvious but I am stuck on this for hours. Can someone please tell me why required is false when I was expecting for it to be true?

Edit: constructors and method calls hierachy

Edit: 
Sysout results:

true

false

Comment: when you have both prints on, do you see them print both (in the wrong order) or is `setRequired` never called (in which case it should imo error because bean config fails)

Comment: Set prints first (value - true) then method prints second (false). Setter gets called. but somehow be overwrite by the default. Not sure what I can do to fix it

Comment: That would mean you're not using the properly initialized bean instance but one you `new`'d yourself or so!?

Comment: Show the class where you're calling this method from.

Comment: it was called from the same class within the method. I will make an edit

Comment: @zapl do you know constructor will have affect on this? if so by adding the variables to constructor will help eliminate this problem?

Comment: @user3659052: The constructor in your code is likely not the cause for your problem.

Comment: @user3659052: Try using the new suggested changes in my answer below it should help.

Comment: sorry vivek your answer does not help.....

Comment: @user3659052 can you let us know from where `trySomething` method is called

Comment: how is `ServiceImpl` injected into `Synch`? You don't seem to be using the `<bean id="service" />` version of it.

Comment: actually you are right, because synch is private abstract class and all of the method in it is either private or protected. In design we not sure if we could autowire this so we didn't. We thought we could independently inject the values as we did for the dao classes.

Answer (score -1):

Make the below changes in your class

```
public class ServiceImpl {
    private Boolean required = false;

    public void doSomething(Collection someList, int someValue) {
        ...
        //sysout(required) - prints false (expected to be true...)
        if(!required) { 
             execute A
        } else {
             execute B
        }
        ...
    }

    public void setRequired(Boolean required){
        this.required = required
        //sysout(required) - prints true
    }
}
```

also in xml file do the below change

```
<bean id="service" class="com.ort.ets.ServiceImpl">
    <property name="required" value="true" />
</bean>
```

should be

```
<bean id="service" class="com.ort.ets.ServiceImpl">
    <property name="required">
        <value type="java.lang.Boolean">true</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

`boolean` must be replaced wtih object type class(`java.lang.Boolean`)

Comment: actually it is setRequired. sorry it was a typo

Comment: And the return type should be `void`. I am surprised it compiles... ;-) The parameter can definitely be `boolean`.

Comment: @user3659052 I have made the necessary changes in my answer. Hope this solves your issue